# Flutter plugin for MoEngage?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, plugins, moengage

How can I integrate a MoEngage in flutter framework. Is there any libraries I can use readily? Do I need to do it separately in iOS and Android? I don't see any official support for flutter by MoEngage team. How do i achieve it in flutter?

Comment: We don't have a flutter package which you can install in your app and use. You can create a package on top of our native Android and iOS SDKs and use it in your Flutter application.

Comment: Just to add to what @Umang mentioned, you don't have to do it separately. You can create a single plugin packages with support for both iOS and Android.
This doc should help you with it -> https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages

Comment: @Rajesh We have implemented a flutter plugin for MoEngage SDK, find more info in the documentation : https://docs.moengage.com/docs/sdk-integration-4

Comment: Hey @ChengappaCD thanks aloot ...ill do check..will notify you if any issue found